# Ajax call triggered by hitting the bottom of the screen not working on android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery, ajax

Hi I have an ajax call that is to be ran when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom of the screen that loads more content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
             //make ajax call and do something on response.
}
});

});
```

This works fine on windows however I have tested it on two different android devices and this does not work.

My html is like this:

```
<div id="main-content">
/* CONTENT HERE */
</div>
<p id="loading-progress">
/* LOADING ANIMATION HERE */
</p>
```

So the loading animation is right at the bottom of the screen, when the user hits the bottom of the screen the ajax call is made for new data which is then appended to the `div` `#main-content` and the loading animation is hidden.

I am stumped as to what could be causing this behaviour on android (maybe ios also; not tested) devices.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me to try?